# I'm looking to implement a better UI Solution for managing content

Tags: speak, content-management, sitecore-client

Has anyone come across this type of feature in the marketplace or created a solution themselves? Mainly thinking about non-technical content managers having the easiest of UI solution for managing content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more details..

Comment: Is this related to Sitecore specifically? You want a UI that's not the Content Editor or Experience Editor?

Comment: You need to be specific about what you want to change.

Comment: I think he is quite clear, he is asking whether we have an alternative UI to the current sitecore speak dashboard, content editor, shell and experience editor views we currently have? and if there is a way to go about making one.

Comment: There can be no such feature; as what you're looking to do always would be project specific. Unless you're looking to rewrite the Sitecore client - which I am assuming you're not.

I agree with comments above though; there's going to need to be a more specific direction for this question, for any meaningful answer to be formed.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Yeah writing my question up I noticed, sitecore has many ways to provide a different experience to the content manager. It can be customized as well, though with some effort. The above can be more specific, will see if poster expands on it before voting to close. My answer hopefully clarifies some of the posters high level unknowns.

Answer (score 3):

To start off, I would always recommend training for someone who needs to make use of a WCMS platform before they go in. There is always going to be so much involved.

One option is using the sitecore apis you could always create a Wizard Tool that works through content creation or managing content for certain pages. The cost and time effort of that would be really high.

Out of the box I generally find, one of the most crucial aspects of making an end-users sitecore content editing experience *great* is the information architecture and the work put in to supporting the Experience Editor. I've linked to the base docs for sitecore regarding both content editor or experience editor below. You'll find quick googles show you how to best support experience editor in different scenarios.

### Experience Editor

> The Experience Editor is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to easily
> make changes to items directly on the page. You can edit all the items
> that are visible on the page — text, graphics, logos, links, and so
> on.
>
> In the Experience Editor, you can edit the fields of the current item
> and the fields of any items rendered on the page. For instance, if the
> menu on the page consists of titles of the product items, you can edit
> the titles without navigating to the product items themselves.

### Content Editor

> The Content Editor is an editing tool that you can use to manage and edit all the content on your website. It is designed for more experienced content authors who are familiar with Sitecore and the functionality that it contains.
>
> The Content Editors appearance and functionality vary depending on the user’s roles, the local security settings, and the customizations that have been implemented on the Sitecore installation.

Worth reading up on: [The Experience Editor](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_experience_editor/the_experience_editor) and [Content Editor](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_content_editor/the_content_editor) and [Other Editing Tools](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools)

### SPEAK UI

If you really want to customise it, I recommend reading into SPEAK UI first which is what powers a lot of the sitecore client currently.

Maybe give creating a new speak application that'll handle displaying or managing content in a manner you are expecting a go. Worth reading: [Speak for newbies part 1 creating a new application](https://mhwelander.net/2014/06/27/speak-for-newbies-part-1-creating-a-new-application/)

I will be honest with you my personal experience has been, forcing me to rip my hair out, but I know there those who appreciate it.

Finally check out https://github.com/Sitecore/speak.theming never tried it myself but seems cool, allowing you to change the default speak colors :), more customization.

### Helix

If your interested in providing the content editors a decent experience in content editor look into the Helix architecture and look at how it works with the information inside sitecores client, especially when you are building the templates. It's a good starting point for a modular approach. Source: http://helix.sitecore.net/